# I deploy firebase but I can not show my live web site. I shows "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" when deployed to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase

The cause of the problem:

When we run the hosting commands, forget! What do you want to use as your public directory?  y throw it away.

Step 1:
First of all build folder , .firebase , .firebaserc , firebase.json
Delete it.

Step 2:

*firebase init Give this command. Give the following steps correctly
1.What do you want to use as your public directory?   build

2.Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?  Yes

3.Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub?   No

4.File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?   Yes

5.npm run build

6.firebase deploy

Comment: Please share your `firebase.json`.

Comment: In your step 4, you overwrote your existing index.html with Firebase's default index.html.  That's why it's displaying the default page.  You need your own index.html there.